# Magento 1.9.2.4 is not hiding unused attribute combinations in configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute, bug, ce-1.9.2.4

I have an issue with my Magento shop based on Magento 1.9.2.4.

In backend if you check the screenshots you'll see that I have 2 attributes (global, dropdown, included for configurable products):

- Size: A / B
- Color: Black / White

After that based on this attributes, you'll see 2 product combinations created:

- A + Black
- B + White

The problem is, when I choose in frontend Size A, in the second dropdown I should see just Black, and hiding White because I don't have a combination like "A + White"

Same for B, in the second dropdown I should see just white, but i see both white and black.

I found that is a bug just on 1.9.2.4 because I installed an older fresh Magento 1.8 and this bug does not exist.

The customer shouldn't be allowed to choose product combinations which are not created in backend. How can I solve this in 1.9.2.4 ?

[image: Backend]

[image: Frontend]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. And i don't know where it cames from.

In my case there was a problem with the following file:

app/design/frontend/yourtemplate/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtlm

Try to replace it with a new version from magento, theme or earlier version.